# How to get Distinct record from JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have implemented a method which gives me specification, but what I want is the query should be as below:

```
Select Distinct * 
From (another select query)
```

I generate query dynamically.

How do I perform the same using specification in Spring Boot?

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem? if yes then please accept that and upvote it will help others. if the problem is still there we will try to help

Answer (score 1):

Write this in the repository

```
@Query(value = "Select Distinct * From (another select query)", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object> findUniqueData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```java
Specification<T> spec = getSpecification();
Specification<T> distinctSpec = (root, query, cb) -> {
    query.distinct(true);
    return spec.toPredicate(root, query, cb);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get distinct records, you have to write a query like this in the repository.

The below query gives the distinct author from the post table.

```
@Query("select distinct author from Post")
    List<String> findUniqueAuthor();
```

Comment: I am using specifications