# hibernate adding Id column field while building query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Hibernate not creating correct query, In API request I have passed sort=employee.firstName that should return records sort by firstName but hibernate some how adding extra field case_id after firstName. I have debug the code and in sort only one field is there which is employee.firstName, so my question is how hibernate is adding case_id to the query.

Below is my API URL.

```
/api/v1/cases?sort=employee.firstName,ASC&size=50&page=0&statusCategories=open,in_progress&filter=caseType:customer_care
```

I have not passes sort by case_id instead sort by firstName is passed.

Hibernate Query below:

```
SELECT
    case0_.case_id AS case_id1_8_,
    case0_.archived_from AS archived_from2_8_,
    case0_.assignee_id AS assignee_id3_8_,
    case0_.status_id AS status_id15_8_,
    case0_.type AS type4_8_,
    case0_.category_id AS category_id5_8_,
    case0_.employeegroup_id AS employeegroup_id11_8_,
    case0_.created_by AS created_by6_8_,
    case0_.created_date AS created_date7_8_,
    case0_.customer_id AS customer_id8_8_,
    case0_.description AS description9_8_,
    case0_.due_date AS due_date10_8_,
    case0_.eventmanager_id AS eventmanager_id12_8_,
    case0_.resolution_date AS resolution_date13_8_,
    case0_.resort_id AS resort_id14_8_,
    case0_.topic AS topic16_8_
FROM
    CASE case0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee client1_ ON
    case0_.created_by = client1_.employee_id
WHERE
    (case0_.status_id IN (
    SELECT
        casestatus2_.case_status_id
    FROM
        case_status casestatus2_
    WHERE
        casestatus2_.category IN (? , ?)))
    AND (case0_.archived_from IS NULL)
    AND case0_.type =?
ORDER BY
    client1_.firstname ASC,
    case0_.case_id ASC offset ? ROWS FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY
```

[Screenshot in debug mode, as u can see the sort variable only having one field][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DRYJ.png

Controller Code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public Page<Case> getCases(@FilterOptions(joinedEntities = { @JoinedEntity(fieldName = "client", filterName = "client"), @JoinedEntity(fieldName = "clientGroup", filterName = "clientGroup"),
    @JoinedEntity(fieldName = "caseStatus", filterName = "caseStatus"), @JoinedEntity(fieldName = "memoCategory", filterName = "memoCategory"),
    @JoinedEntity(fieldName = "employee", filterName = "employee") }) Specification<Case> specifications, Pageable pageable, CaseFilter caseFilter) {
    return caseService.getCases(specifications, pageable, caseFilter);
  }
```

Domain Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "case")
@DynamicJsonView
@DynamicUpdate
public class Case implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_CASE")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_CASE", sequenceName = "SEQ_CASE", allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "case_id")
  private Long caseId;

  @Column(name = "topic")
  @NotNull
  private String topic;

  @Column(name = "description")
  private String description;

  @Column(name = "status_id")
  private Long statusId;

  @Column(name = "assignee_id")
  private Long assigneeId;

  @Column(name = "customer_id")
  private Long customerId;

  @Column(name = "created_date")
  private LocalDateTime creationDate;

  @Column(name = "due_date")
  private LocalDate dueDate;

  @Column(name = "resolution_date")
  private LocalDate resolutionDate;

  @Column(name = "category_id")
  private Long categoryId;

  @Column(name = "archived_from")
  private LocalDate archivedFrom;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "assignee_id", referencedColumnName = "employee_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Client client;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "employeegroup_id", referencedColumnName = "employeegroup_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @JsonIgnore
  private ClientGroup clientGroup;

  @OneToOne
  @JsonIgnore
  @JoinColumn(name = "status_id", referencedColumnName = "case_status_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private CaseStatus caseStatus;

  @OneToOne
  @JsonIgnore
  @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "memocategory_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private MemoCategory memoCategory;

  @Column(name = "employeegroup_id")
  private Long employeeGroupId;

  @Column(name = "created_by")
  private Long createdBy;

  @Column(name = "resort_id")
  private Long resortId;

  @Column(name = "type")
  private CaseType caseType;

  @Column(name = "eventmanager_id")
  private Long eventManagerId;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "created_by", referencedColumnName = "employee_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Client employee;

  public Long getEventManagerId() {
    return eventManagerId;
  }

  public void setEventManagerId(Long eventManagerId) {
    this.eventManagerId = eventManagerId;
  }

  public CaseType getCaseType() {
    return caseType;
  }

  public void setCaseType(CaseType caseType) {
    this.caseType = caseType;
  }

  public Long getResortId() {
    return resortId;
  }

  public void setResortId(Long resortId) {
    this.resortId = resortId;
  }

  public Long getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
  }

  public void setCreatedBy(Long createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
  }

  public Long getEmployeeGroupId() {
    return employeeGroupId;
  }

  public void setEmployeeGroupId(Long employeeGroupId) {
    this.employeeGroupId = employeeGroupId;
  }

  public LocalDate getArchivedFrom() {
    return archivedFrom;
  }

  public void setArchivedFrom(LocalDate archivedFrom) {
    this.archivedFrom = archivedFrom;
  }

  public Long getCaseId() {
    return caseId;
  }

  public void setCaseId(Long caseId) {
    this.caseId = caseId;
  }

  public String getTopic() {
    return topic;
  }

  public void setTopic(String topic) {
    this.topic = topic;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public Long getStatusId() {
    return statusId;
  }

  public void setStatusId(Long statusId) {
    this.statusId = statusId;
  }

  public Long getAssigneeId() {
    return assigneeId;
  }

  public void setAssigneeId(Long assigneeId) {
    this.assigneeId = assigneeId;
  }

  public Long getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
  }

  public void setCustomerId(Long customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
  }

  public LocalDateTime getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
  }

  public void setCreationDate(LocalDateTime creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
  }

  public LocalDate getDueDate() {
    return dueDate;
  }

  public void setDueDate(LocalDate dueDate) {
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
  }

  public LocalDate getResolutionDate() {
    return resolutionDate;
  }

  public void setResolutionDate(LocalDate resolutionDate) {
    this.resolutionDate = resolutionDate;
  }

  public Long getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
  }

  public void setCategoryId(Long categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((archivedFrom == null) ? 0 : archivedFrom.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((assigneeId == null) ? 0 : assigneeId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((caseId == null) ? 0 : caseId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((caseStatus == null) ? 0 : caseStatus.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((caseType == null) ? 0 : caseType.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((categoryId == null) ? 0 : categoryId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((client == null) ? 0 : client.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((clientGroup == null) ? 0 : clientGroup.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((createdBy == null) ? 0 : createdBy.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((creationDate == null) ? 0 : creationDate.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((customerId == null) ? 0 : customerId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((description == null) ? 0 : description.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((dueDate == null) ? 0 : dueDate.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((employee == null) ? 0 : employee.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((employeeGroupId == null) ? 0 : employeeGroupId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((eventManagerId == null) ? 0 : eventManagerId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((memoCategory == null) ? 0 : memoCategory.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((resolutionDate == null) ? 0 : resolutionDate.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((resortId == null) ? 0 : resortId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((statusId == null) ? 0 : statusId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((topic == null) ? 0 : topic.hashCode());
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
      return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    Case other = (Case) obj;
    if (archivedFrom == null) {
      if (other.archivedFrom != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!archivedFrom.equals(other.archivedFrom)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (assigneeId == null) {
      if (other.assigneeId != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!assigneeId.equals(other.assigneeId)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (caseId == null) {
      if (other.caseId != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!caseId.equals(other.caseId)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (caseStatus == null) {
      if (other.caseStatus != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!caseStatus.equals(other.caseStatus)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (caseType != other.caseType) {
      return false;
    }
    if (categoryId == null) {
      if (other.categoryId != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!categoryId.equals(other.categoryId)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (client == null) {
      if (other.client != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!client.equals(other.client)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (clientGroup == null) {
      if (other.clientGroup != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!clientGroup.equals(other.clientGroup)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (createdBy == null) {
      if (other.createdBy != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!createdBy.equals(other.createdBy)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (creationDate == null) {
      if (other.creationDate != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!creationDate.equals(other.creationDate)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (customerId == null) {
      if (other.customerId != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!customerId.equals(other.customerId)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (description == null) {
      if (other.description != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!description.equals(other.description)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (dueDate == null) {
      if (other.dueDate != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!dueDate.equals(other.dueDate)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (employee == null) {
      if (other.employee != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!employee.equals(other.employee)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (employeeGroupId == null) {
      if (other.employeeGroupId != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!employeeGroupId.equals(other.employeeGroupId)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (eventManagerId == null) {
      if (other.eventManagerId != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!eventManagerId.equals(other.eventManagerId)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (memoCategory == null) {
      if (other.memoCategory != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!memoCategory.equals(other.memoCategory)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (resolutionDate == null) {
      if (other.resolutionDate != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!resolutionDate.equals(other.resolutionDate)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (resortId == null) {
      if (other.resortId != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!resortId.equals(other.resortId)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (statusId == null) {
      if (other.statusId != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!statusId.equals(other.statusId)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (topic == null) {
      if (other.topic != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (!topic.equals(other.topic)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Repositery Code:

```
    @Repository
public interface CaseRepository extends MaxxtonJpaRepository<Case, Long> {

  @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT assignee_id FROM case WHERE assignee_id IN (SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE group_Id= :employeeGroupId ) group by assignee_id")
  public List<Long> fetchEmployees(@Param(value = "employeeGroupId") Long employeeGroupId);

}
```

Another Repositery class:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MaxxtonJpaRepository<ENTITY, ID extends Serializable> extends FieldFilterRepository<ENTITY, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ENTITY> {
  <P> List<P> findAll(Specification<ENTITY> spec, Class<P> projection);
  <P> Page<P> findAll(Specification<ENTITY> specification, Class<P> projection, Pageable pageable);
  ENTITY saveAndRefresh(ENTITY entity);
  Iterable<ENTITY> saveAllAndRefresh(Iterable<ENTITY> entities);
}
```

How this case_id gets added in order by.

Comment: Without seeing your controller and your repository method, mapping this is going to be impossible to answer.

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: Still there is too little information. Without the service this will, still, be impossible to answer. Why isn't the sorting part of the `Pageable` but rather the `CaseFilter`. Which can only mean you are creating a query (dynamically) yourself. There is also some `Predicates` added to your controller, not sure what they are from.

Comment: You have some custom implementation for those `findAll` methods as those aren't part of the regular Spring Data portfolio. Also those `@FilterOptions` is either something custom or another framework you are using. There are more moving parts and complexity then "just executing a query" in this.

Comment: I do have posted one another problem can u help to solve it, link https://stackoverflow.com/q/68361982/16439217